# Replicate filter in excel

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to create an excel file that essentially 'tidies up' one of our customer's Bill of Materials when it is pasted onto a separate tab.

The customer's BOM is supplied like so: https://i.stack.imgur.com/erUgl.jpg

I have used this excel function to pull only the relevant data through and match it with the location in the same row - =IF((LEN(D8)<2),0,(LOOKUP(2,1/(C$1:C8<>""),C:C)))

Which leaves me with this: imgur(dot)com/3z4MXfs

Ideally I'd like to be able to run a macro that shows the data on another sheet with the blank or zero'ed rows deleted, like so: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0keYz.jpg (without altering the original BOM on the other tab)

Does anyone have an idea how I would go about doing this?

Thank you

Comment: Please post sample data so we don't have to type it out....

Comment: Hi Brendan, 

Sample data in the link below; https://www.dropbox.com/s/gcjwqcf7qi9kzmc/BOM.xls?dl=0

Comment: If you are *'trying to create an excel file'* then kindly show what you have come up with so far and note any problem areas or error messages. This question is Off Topic for [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) because it has **no** potential for helping future viewers of this thread. [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) is **not** your personal, free code-writing service. If you have taken on a job that is beyond your abilities then repost your software spec at [Stack Overflow Jobs](http://stackoverflow.com/jobs). I regret that I have only one down-vote to give.

Comment: Hi @JRS192 please see code below, let me know if it helps....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will copy your formula results onto the second sheet, ignoring blank or 'zero' rows

```
Sub CopyRows()
Dim RowNo, LastRow, NewRowNo As Long
LastRow = Sheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row
RowNo = 1
NewRowNo = 1

Sheets(2).Cells.Clear

Do Until RowNo = LastRow

    If Sheets(1).Cells(RowNo, 10) = "" Or Sheets(1).Cells(RowNo, 10) = "0" Then

    RowNo = RowNo + 1

    Else: 

    Sheets(2).Cells(NewRowNo, 1) = Sheets(1).Cells(RowNo, 10)
    Sheets(2).Cells(NewRowNo, 2) = Sheets(1).Cells(RowNo, 11)

    RowNo = RowNo + 1
    NewRowNo = NewRowNo + 1

    End If
    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks @JRS192 I'm glad this helps you :) I would appreciate you marking this as the correct answer and an upvote if you're feeling generous :)